# Jacobian in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I see many people asking this question here but I didn't see a code that I can execute. I am trying to make two operations, to get dOuput/dInput and to get dOutput/dParameters. I tried

```py
    # gradient method 1
    jac_Action_wrt_Param = tf.pack([tf.concat(1, [tf.reshape(tf.gradients(action_output[:, idx], param)[0], [1, -1])
                                                  for param in learnable_param_list]) for idx in range(action_dim)],
                                   axis=1, name='jac_Action_wrt_Param')
    jac_Action_wrt_State = tf.pack(
        [tf.gradients(action_output[:, idx], state_input)[0] for idx in range(action_dim)], axis=1,
        name='jac_Action_wrt_State')
```

here state is input and action is output. Both methods give None... What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that code was working perfectly fine. I was calling session call wrong.  Now we have a working example in StackOverflow ;)

Comment: maybe one issue is that the first derivative is not computed per sample wise but summed up. Can I get jacobians per sample without specifying the batch size?

Comment: You have to call derivative with respect to each sample if you want multiple results

Comment: The problem here is that the batch size is not known. I cannot simply use for loops here.

Comment: Can you fix batch size? If the batch size is variable, then this is going to be tricky. TensorFlow doesn't make a distinction between examples as vectors, examples as columns or examples as matrices....there isn't a "summing up of row examples" step you can turn off, it's a single matrix-valued example for differentiation purposes

Comment: The batch size is not known. It'll be called by different functions. I guess then the best way is stacking the computed values after multiple gradient calls. Thank you for your answer!